# What are the effects of oxygen toxicity in human blood?

Tags: human-biology, hematology, human-physiology, blood-circulation

I was reading some text on deep sea Physiology, and for to know that diving to do could cause oxygen toxicity in the blood. This was the exact text from the book **Textbook of Medical Physiology by Arthur Guyton and John E. Hall:**

> A  column  of seawater  33  feet  (10.1  meters)  deep  exerts  the  same  pressure  at  its  bottom  as  the  pressure  of  the  atmosphere  above the  sea.  Therefore,  a  person  33  feet  beneath  the  ocean surface  is  exposed  to  2  atmospheres  pressure,  with  1  atmosphere  of  pressure  caused  by  the  weight  of  the  air  above the  water  and  the  second  atmosphere caused by the weight of  the  water.
>
> When  the  PO2  in  the  blood  rises  above  100  mm  Hg, the  amount  of  O2  dissolved  in  the  water  of  the  blood increases  markedly. Note  that in  the  normal  range  of  alveolar  PO2  (below  120  mm  Hg), almost  none  of  the  total  O2  in  the  blood  is  accounted  for by  dissolved  O2,  but  as  the  O2  pressure  rises  into  the thousands  of  millimeters  of  mercury,  a  large  portion  of the  total  O2  is  then  dissolved  in  the  water  of  the  blood,  in addition  to  that  bound  with  hemoglobin.

I understand that high pressure causes more oxygen to dissolve in blood, but **cannot figure out how excess dissolved oxygen in the blood disturbs the normal physiological balance of the body.**

I'd be grateful if someone knowing the answer can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from a Wikipedia article:

Central nervous system oxygen toxicity manifests as symptoms such as visual changes (especially tunnel vision), ringing in the ears (tinnitus), nausea, twitching (especially of the face), behavioural changes (irritability, anxiety, confusion), and dizziness.
Oxygen toxicity - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity

It says there's hemolysis of red blood cells - i.e., they lyse = break open.